# awk print out file with a row number

Tags: awk, printing

I want to print out a file that has 1 column listing values like:

```
cat
dog
house
```

But I want to have the file print like this to another file:

```
1 cat
2 dog
3 house
```

I think that awk could be used to do this?

Can you provide the command to do that? I know I need to do something like this to print the file:

```
awk -F '{ print $1 }'
```

But would I do something like this:

```
int i
awk -F '{ print i, " " $1 }'
i++
```

(Left my awk book at work)

Comment: `cat -n` would do this job.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with `NR` (Number of Records):

```
awk '{ print NR, $1 }'
```

Example:

```
$ echo -e "test test\ntest test" | awk -F'\n' '{print NR, $1}'
1 test test
2 test test
```

Comment: I'm looking to see how to get it to read multiple lines, the way i did it, I only get one line. Can you suggest else I need to do to get all the lines of the file? cat object_list.tsv |awk '{ print NR, $1 }'. Perhaps it is because it is a tab separated file.

Comment: If it's tab separated, try using `-F'\t'` for it to split at the tabs.

Comment: do you have to use non-standard prompts here?  especially one that looks like a bolded redirection operator?  I'm sure you think it looks pretty but please stick to the convention of `$` for non-root prompt, `#` for root prompt, and `%` for csh.

Comment: @cas Forgot to change it.

Comment: If you just want to keep the whole input line, don't bother with `-F` and do `awk '{print NR,$0}'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use rows and columns restrictions, for instance:

I'd like to show the %idle average of cpu, like the picture:

[image: iostat]

so, you can use the command:

```
 iostat | awk 'NR==4{print $6}'
```

Result:
[image: iostat | awk 'NR==4{print $6}']

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the OP is not asking how to print a specific column of a given line, but how to prefix the output of a given column with the line number.